# Change both background image AND color on refresh

Tags: jquery, css, background, background-image, background-color

I'm attempting to have the background image AND color change on refresh. I can randomizing the background image, but not color.

For example:
bg-1.jpg - color 1
bg-2.jpg - color 2
bg-3.jpg - color 3

I know I can randomize the image, I just can't get a matching color for each image with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bgArray = ['A-VOLTE.jpg', 'AL-DI-LA.jpg', 'CON-TE.jpg', 'DAVIDE-E-GOLIA.jpg', 'DELLE-VERITA.jpg', 'DI-NOI.jpg', 'DIVIDERE.jpg', 'FA-NIENTE.jpg', 'FORSE.jpg', 'GRAZIE.jpg', 'IL-CONTATTO.jpg', 'IL-PONTE.jpg', 'IMPERATIVO.jpg', 'INDELEBILE.jpg', '-VOLONTA.jpg', 'MERITAVI.jpg', 'MUOVERE.jpg', 'NEL-DUBBIO.jpg', 'NESSUNO.jpg', 'NON-LO-SAI.jpg', 'PER-DIMENTICARE.jpg', 'PRIMA-DI-ANDARE.jpg', 'PROFONDO.jpg', 'SARA-SUO.jpg', 'SEMPRE.jpg', 'TUTTO-DA-RIFARE.jpg', 'TUTTO-PER-TE.jpg', 'UN-RICORDO.jpg', 'UNTITLED-1.jpg', 'UNTITLED-2.jpg', 'VERO.jpg', 'VIENI-CON-ME.jpg'];
  var bg = bgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.length)];
  var path = 'artworks/abstract/';
  var imageUrl = path + bg;
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl +')');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an array containing matching colour codes for each of your background, and then add as a style to your `body`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bgArray = ['...'];
  var colorsArray = ['...'];
  var rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.length);
  var bg = bgArray[rng];
  var color = colorsArray[rng];

  var path = 'artworks/abstract/';
  var imageUrl = path + bg;
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl +')');
  $('body').css('background-color', color);
});
```

In this case, you will get a matching `bg` and `color` provided that the matching colour is of the same index (in `colorsArray`) as the background (in `bgArray`).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmrfv87v/).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help! Can't believe how much I had to have over think this!

Comment: No problem! If it helps, consider accepting this as the answer.